# Kotlin Sequence type inference

Tags: kotlin

I'm having trouble solving the following issue:

```
class Node(val next: Node?) {

    fun asSequence(): Sequence<Node> = sequence {
        var node: Node? = this@Node;
        while (node != null) {
            yield(node)
            node = node.next
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler is obviously failing:

```
Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Sequence<Node?> but Sequence<Node> was expected
```

I do want the sequence to be `Sequence<Node>` not `Sequence<Node?>` and it should be possible because `yield()` is behind a null check.

When I change `yield(node)` to either `yield(node!!)` or `yield(node as Node)`, the type inference works but now I get compiler warnings telling me:

```
Unnecessary non-null assertion (!!) on a non-null receiver of type Node
```

How to I create a `Sequence<Node>` without compiler warnings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the Kotlin compiler issue. You can help compiler a bit and set the type of sequence explicitly while it's not fixed

```
class Node(val next: Node?) {
    fun asSequence(): Sequence<Node> = sequence<Node> {
        var node: Node? = this@Node;
        while (node != null) {
            yield(node)
            node = node.next
        }
    }
}
```